# JAXRPCSERVLET28: Missing port information

Tags: jboss, webservice-client

Reason for this error JAXRPCSERVLET28: Missing port information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my server had some issues coming up after a bounce.. I think that made to throw this error. We bounced the server and the server is back up now and it is working....

Note : this service was working before. So I think bounce fixed our issue. I just wanted to post this here because I see many post for this error without a solution

Please include if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

From my research, the following stack trace shows the location of error; it also provides information that the _send() method is where the error occurs:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: JAXRPC.JAXRPCSERVLET.28: Missing port information
=09at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StreamingSender._raiseFault(StreamingSender.ja=
va:372)
=09at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.StreamingSender._send(StreamingSender.java:224=
)
=09at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.dii.CallInvokerImpl.doInvoke(CallInvokerImpl.j=
ava:61)
=09at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.dii.BasicCall.invoke(BasicCall.java:339)
=09at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.dii.CallInvocationHandler.doCall(CallInvocatio=
nHandler.java:99)
=09at com.sun.xml.rpc.client.dii.CallInvocationHandler.invoke(CallInvocatio=
nHandler.java:71)
=09at $Proxy0.getWorkList(Unknown Source)
=09at com.workpoint.sample.client.webservices.WorkItemServiceClient.testGet=
WorkList(WorkItemServiceClient.java:124)
=09at com.workpoint.sample.client.webservices.WorkItemServiceClient.main(Wo=
rkItemServiceClient.java:48)
=09
```

This problem was resolved for me when I looked at the server.log file and saw that the JAXRPC servlet did not deploy correctly because of an initialization issue.  The war file successfully deployed.  Beware: after running tests, the original error in the server.log file will be 'left behind', fronted by other log activity that was not helpful.  This error could be caused by any number of causes.